# Truffle build isn't working

Tags: solidity, truffle

I installed truffle via this command:

```
sudo npm install -g truffle
```

Then I installed `testrpc` via this command

```
sudo npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

Then I started `testrpc` via this command

```
testrpc
```

It began to run successfully. Then I created a folder and initiated `truffle` project  via this command.

```
truffle init
```

Then I compiled it via this command

```
truffle compile
```

Then I migrated that truffle project via this command

```
truffle migrate
```

Now I want to add `DAPPS` support, so I built that truffle project via this command

```
truffle build
```

But when I ran that command, I got this error

```
Error building:

No build configuration specified. Can't build.

Build failed. See above.
```

My `truffle` version is

```
Truffle v3.4.9 (core: 3.4.8)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)
```

How can I fix that error, it seems to be a bug [as given here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/324).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a build process. http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/build_processes

It is stated in their documentation:

> Note you'll receive an error if you try to run the build command without first configuring a custom build process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a file in the home folder called truffle.js
This should be created automatically when you type in `truffle init`
Then you need to modify this file. an example of mine pointing to my local testrpc looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
     development: {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 8545,
       network_id: "*" // Match any network id
     }
   },
   mocha: {
    useColors: true
   }
};
```

But if you are not using the testRPC and using truffles own test engine, then comment out the block as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
  //  testrpc: {
  //    host: "localhost",
  //    port: 8545,
  //    network_id: "*" // Match any network id
  //  }
  }
};
```

This should work currently.